# Chart con datos de SQLServer c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

tengo una base de datos la cual me gustaría mostrar en un chart, hasta ahora estaba accediendo a la consulta por fechas de la siguiente manera filtrando consultas en fechas:

```
     string fechaDesde = dateGraficoDiarioDesde.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        string fechaHasta = dateGraficoDiarioHasta.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

        string query = "SELECT * FROM minutales WHERE FechaHora BETWEEN '" + fechaDesde + "' AND '" + fechaHasta + "' ";
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(conexion);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, cn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
```

La tabla tiene el siguiente aspecto:

[image: tabla]

Me gustaría representar el eje x variado por las fechas que se seleccionan en el dateTimePickers dateGraficoDiarioDesde y dateGraficoDiarioHasta, el eje y va a ser fijo en un valor 1000, y las series serian el dato PLC1Particulas y PLC1Presion. Alguien me puede ayudar con la representación en un chart? Como puedo acceder al valor en concreto de cada serie en la base de datos y mostrarlo? y como puedo modificar el eje x para que adopte el valor de las fechas consultadas? Sería del siguiente estilo. Muchas gracias

[image: grafico]

Comment: que tipo de grafico usa, no puedo ver tu imagen?

Comment: chart, lo he resuelto, publico la respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He conseguido hacer la representación de la siguiente manera por si a alguien le sirve:

```
    chartMinutal.Series.Clear();
            chartMinutal.ChartAreas.Clear();
            chartMinutal.ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea1");
            chartMinutal.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            chartMinutal.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LineColor = Color.Transparent;
            chartMinutal.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorTickMark.LineColor = Color.Transparent;
            chartMinutal.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Transparent;
            chartMinutal.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
            chartMinutal.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LineColor = Color.White;
            chartMinutal.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorTickMark.LineColor = Color.Transparent;
            chartMinutal.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Transparent;
            chartMinutal.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.LabelStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
            chartMinutal.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.LineColor = Color.White;
            chartMinutal.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY2.Enabled = AxisEnabled.True;
            chartMinutal.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY2.MajorTickMark.LineColor = Color.Transparent;
            chartMinutal.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY2.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Transparent;
            chartMinutal.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY2.LabelStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
            chartMinutal.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY2.LineColor = Color.White;


            if (cbFiltrosGraficoMinutal.Text.Trim() == "Filtro1" || cbFiltrosGraficoMinutal.Text.Trim() == "Filtro2" || cbFiltrosGraficoMinutal.Text.Trim() == "Filtro4" ||
                cbFiltrosGraficoMinutal.Text.Trim() == "Filtro5" || cbFiltrosGraficoMinutal.Text.Trim() == "Filtro6")
            {
               string query = @"SELECT Q.FECHA, SUM(q.PARTICULAS) AS PARTICULAS , SUM(q.PRESION) AS PRESION, sum(q.PRESIONDIF) AS 
                           PRESIONDIF,
                           SUM(Q.TEMPERATURASONDA) AS TEMPERATURASONDA, SUM(Q.TEMPERATURA) AS TEMPERATURA, SUM(Q.CAUDAL) AS
                           CAUDAL
                           FROM(
                           SELECT  Fecha as FECHA, particulas as PARTICULAS, 0 as PRESION, 0
                           as PRESIONDIF, 0 AS TEMPERATURASONDA, 0 AS TEMPERATURA,
                           0 AS CAUDAL
                           FROM " + cbFiltrosGraficoMinutal.Text.Trim().ToLower() +
                           @" WHERE flag1 = '0' and Fecha BETWEEN @FechaDesde and @FechaHasta GROUP BY fecha, particulas
                           UNION
                           SELECT  Fecha as FECHA, 0 AS PARTICULAS, presion as PRESION, 0 as PRESIONDIF, 0
                           AS TEMPERATURASONDA, 0 AS TEMPERATURA,
                           0 AS CAUDAL
                           FROM  " + cbFiltrosGraficoMinutal.Text.Trim().ToLower() +
                           @"  WHERE flag2 = '0' and Fecha BETWEEN @FechaDesde and @FechaHasta  GROUP BY Fecha, presion                 
                           ) q
                           GROUP BY Q.FECHA";

                SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(conexion);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, cn);

                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FechaDesde", Convert.ToDateTime(dateGraficoMinutal.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ' ' + timeDesdeGraficoMinutal.Value.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"))));
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FechaHasta", Convert.ToDateTime(dateGraficoMinutal.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ' ' + timeHastaGraficoMinutal.Value.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"))));

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);

                if (cbGraficosMinutal1.Text == "PARTICULAS")
                {
                    chartMinutal.Series.Add("Particulas");
                    chartMinutal.Series["Particulas"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
                    chartMinutal.Series["Particulas"].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
                    chartMinutal.Series["Particulas"].MarkerColor = Color.Lime;
                    chartMinutal.Series["Particulas"].Color = Color.Lime;
                    chartMinutal.Series["Particulas"].ToolTip = "#VALX #VALY mg/m3";
                    chartMinutal.Series["Particulas"].MarkerSize = 5;

                    chartMinutal.Series["Particulas"].XValueType = ChartValueType.Time;
                    chartMinutal.Series["Particulas"].IsXValueIndexed = false;
                    chartMinutal.Series["Particulas"].XValueMember = "Fecha";
                    chartMinutal.Series["Particulas"].YValueMembers = "PARTICULAS";

                }

                else if (cbGraficosMinutal1.Text == "PRESION")
                {
                    chartMinutal.Series.Add("Presion");
                    chartMinutal.Series["Presion"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
                    chartMinutal.Series["Presion"].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
                    chartMinutal.Series["Presion"].MarkerColor = Color.Yellow;
                    chartMinutal.Series["Presion"].Color = Color.Yellow;
                    chartMinutal.Series["Presion"].ToolTip = "#VALX #VALY mb";
                    chartMinutal.Series["Presion"].MarkerSize = 5;

                    chartMinutal.Series["Presion"].XValueType = ChartValueType.Time;
                    chartMinutal.Series["Presion"].IsXValueIndexed = false;
                    chartMinutal.Series["Presion"].XValueMember = "Fecha";

                    chartMinutal.Series["Presion"].YValueMembers = "PRESION";
                }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: puedes complementar tu respuesta con el codigo completo de tu chart?

Comment: A qué te refieres? Al diseño gráfico?

Comment: al codigo ya que solo pones como asignas el value a las X y Y pero no como declaras las series del chart

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta como finalmente lo deje

Comment: ok ya veo, el unico detalle es que yo quiero cambiar de color algunas columnas de la misma serie, en tu caso tienes dos series y cargas una o la otra, continuare buscando, saludos.

Comment: tu grafico es igual que este lineal?